# SocialEngine 4 cropped URLs

Tags: php, url, socialengine

Nice to meet you, stackoverflow!
I have a little question about SocialEngine 4.. it is possible to have longer URLs?
I mean I need longer titles from topics is forum, so I edited Create.php and Edit.php files in application/modules/Forum/Topic dir and also edited title length in database..
But SE keeps cropping my URLs after 64 characters so I need topic URL to be as long as the title is. 
Could you help me to solve that? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the length in model getHref function where getSlug function called.

$this->getSlug(null, 100);

Or

parent::getSlug($title, 100);

100 is the length of title, you can change it as per your requirement.